# Manual ssh-add works but fails when run from shell script in Ansible. ssh-agent forwarding

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

When I run the following commands manually [one after the other], the ssh-agent forwarding works with remote hosts:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add <>.pem
```

But, when I bundle them in a shell script and run as an Ansible play, the ssh forwarding doesn't work. Like this:

```
   changed: [localhost] => {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "sh test.sh",
        "delta": "0:00:00.008763",
        "end": "2017-03-29 12:10:12.337557",
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "_raw_params": "sh test.sh",
                "_uses_shell": true,
                "chdir": null,
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "removes": null,
                "warn": true
            },
            "module_name": "command"
        },
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2017-03-29 12:10:12.328794",
        "stderr": "Identity added: <>.pem (<>.pem)",
        "stdout": "Agent pid <>",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "Agent pid <>"
        ],
        "warnings": []
    }
```

It returns this same error:

```
fatal: [<>]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

My ansible.cfg looks like this:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args=-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath=/tmp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

**So, how do I enable ssh-agent forwarding (maybe via ansible itself?) without manually entering the ssh-add commands in the host?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#private-key-file

Add the pem file in path to avoid unnecessary complications.